# a project involving training for children, teachers, and parents(,) was the most effective

Tags: commas, comma-splices, oxford-comma, parenthetical-commas

is adding the comma before was necessary?

a project involving training for children, teachers, and parents(**,**) was the most effective

Comment: Never separate the subject from its verb. A parenthetical insertion is possible — as in your other question — but rare. Here, you're separating the qualified *project* from *was*.

Answer (score 0):

My gut tells me to leave it out as you are neither adding a new item (I.e. commata to enumerate different entities) nor are you closing a parenthesis.

Similarly, if the enumerarion of persons is removed, it reads fine for me:

...a project was the most effective.